# Updating input value [HTML/JS]

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a problem with updating values in input filed [HTML].
Is it possible to update them on change? I tried to do it this way (i used code that i found on this site):

```
<input type="text" id='user' value='user' onchange="updateInput(this.value)"><br>

<script>
var cc2 = document.getElementById("user").value;

function updateInput(ish){
document.getElementById("user").value = ish;
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="alert(cc2)">test</a>
```

After pressing "test" link I am still receiving alert with value: "user" no matter what i put in input.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is: Is is possible to get the proper (updated) value from the input? Lets say i loaded page - calue field contains "user", now i put another value insead of it, for example "user2". For now i still get value "user" after pressing test link.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your updateInput with following code

```
function updateInput(ish){
cc2=ish;
}
```

This will assign the value of your input to cc2 var. So on each change in input will make cc2 to holds the latest value.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys. 
Totally forgot about that.

Putting another cc2 assigment inside function made it work.