# How to make a copy button to copy input text from another field?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a copy button that copies another textfield to the current one.

Here is my code of the field I want to copy

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <textarea class="form-control" row="5" col="10" 
           id="alamat_tempat_tinggal" 
            name="alamat_tempat_tinggal" 
            onchange="update_data()" >
           <?=@$registration->address?>
   </textarea>
</div>
```

here is the code of the filed i want to copy to

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Alamat Surat Menyurat<span class=" text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type=button id="copy_asm_address" onclick="copy_alamat_asm_address()" value = "Sama Dengan Alamat Tinggal">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
       <textarea class="form-control" row="5" col="10"  name="asm_address" id="asm_address" onchange="update_data()"><?=@$registration->ASM_address?></textarea>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the function

```
function copy_alamat_asm_address(){
    var alamat = document.getElementById("alamat_tempat_tinggal").val();
    document.getElementById("asm_address").value = alamat;
}
```

Comment: getElementsByName returns array of elements . You need too use getElementById

Comment: getElementsByName returns an array, so you need to take the first element in the arrays if you have only one element with the name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating input value \[HTML/JS\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298955/updating-input-value-html-js)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` "Returns a nodelist collection with a given name in the (X)HTML document." ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName))

This is not what you're after: you want to select one element to copy the value.

Use `getElementById` instead, and make sure you only use each ID once in your page.

```
function copy_alamat_asm_address(){
var alamat = document.getElementById("copy_asm_address").value();
document.getElementById("copy_to_field").value = alamat;
}
```

Next to that, to get the value of an input field, you need `.value()`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Alamat Surat Menyurat<span class=" text-danger">*</span></label>
    <input type=button id="copy_asm_address" onclick="copy_alamat_asm_address()" value = "Sama Dengan Alamat Tinggal">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
       <textarea class="form-control" row="5" col="10" name="asm_address" onchange="update_data()" id="copy_to_field"><?=@$registration->ASM_address?></textarea>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: i make the change still, it doesn't working.
var alamat = document.getElementById("alamat_tinggal").val();
    alert(alamat);
    document.getElementById("asm_address").value = alamat;

Comment: Use `.value()` instead of `'.val()`

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is jQuery.  You need to use `.value()`.